# Optimizing Speed for Image Heavy Wordpress Blog

Tags: performance, wordpress, optimization

I'm working on a clients existing Wordpress Blog and the layout is image heavy. I did a speed test with Pingdom Tools and it is SLOW! Here were the results:

```
Total loading time:
    29.9 seconds
Total objects:
    172 (1631.5 KB)
External objects:
    24 (536.2 KB)
HTML (X)HTML:
    3 (39.8KB)
RSS RSS/XML:
    0
CSS CSS:
    25 (206.4KB)
Scripts Scripts:
    43 (754KB)
Images Images:
    95 (346KB)
Plugins Plugins:
    0
Other Other:
    6 (285.3KB)
Redirected Redirected:
    1
```

Almost 30 seconds! What are some things I can do besides caching the page? would using CDN be a good idea? I tried using minify plugins, but they keep breaking the pages. The website is on a shared server (Bluehost).

Comment: First port of call: [WP Super cache.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) Although 800k of scripts really is a *lot*. What do all those scripts do?

Comment: I went through the scripts and only two are actually used on the homepage. I don't know what the other scripts are for. I think they are just loading, but not being used. I tried Super Cache, but it breaks the website and I can't seem to get page exclusion to work.

Comment: The website includes an two e-commerce solutions and a subscribers portion of the website. So, yea alot of plugins are involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should use [Web Page Analyzer](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/) to test the website and the results will give you several solutions to speed up the site. Your overall goal should be to get every recommendation green.

Start by reducing the number of HTTP requests which can be done by suing a minification, this combines the number of output files and groups them into a single file e.g. 10 .js files become 1 js file. I suggest using the [W3Total Cache Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) to do this.

If the site has a ton of images you'll also want to make sure each image has been optimized using [Photoshop's Save For Web option](http://www.rdesignonline.com/design/photoshop-save-for-web-explained/) this can dramatically decrease the image loading times. You'll want to create a batch to do this so you can optimize all the images in one swoop.

I've also installed the WordPress plugin [jQuery Image Lazy Load WP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-image-lazy-loading/) and this works well to speed up users perception of the site.

Comment: thanks, I've tried the jQuery Image Load plugin... The problem with it is that it messes up a slide show that I have on my front page. I wish there was a way for the script to exclude particular scripts... then it would be perfect.

Comment: Here's the answer on how to exclude certain DIV's, ID's and Classes names here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-jquery-image-lazy-load-wp-custom-loading-of-multiple-rows-of-pictures?replies=9

Comment: Wow, thanks. I just need to figure out how to implement the code given on the page since the plugin uses shortcode to implement the slideshows. Its "uBillboard"... don't know if you've heard of it.

Comment: No I've never seen uBillboard before but you can get support for it here http://codecanyon.net/item/ubillboard-premium-slider-for-wordpress/full_screen_preview/124783. The class you need to add to the code referenced above is for uds-stage so the code would be jQuery("div").not(".uds-stage").find("img").lazyload

Comment: .... I would pay dividends to have the level of knowledge you have on this stuff. I'm just confused on where I can implement the code. The plugin gives shortcode for us to use on pages or widgets. I guess I will take a look in the plugin folder. Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: Looks like to me you can Edit this file: jq_img_lazy_load.php Look for the <script> tag and you'll find the proper code there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google's PageSpeed Insights, as well as GTMetrix, both analyze and suggest compression needed for already published images. Following the recommendation obtained from either one of the tool, navigate over to TinyPNG to resize those images and then re-upload. It uses smart lossy compression to reduce file size for PNG and JPG images while preserving full alpha transparency. Output provided is much smaller in size and better in quality than Photoshop's.